# Precompile Directives on Using directive in .NET

Tags: c#, directive, using-statement, precompile

Is doing the following consider bad practice or could it have consequence which would lead one to not do this?

```
#if DEBUG
using Moq;
#endif
```

This is in a single file where a single method which uses the Moq using statement is also in a similar conditional (such as):

```
#if DEBUG
public my_object MyAction(Mock<my_object> obj) { ... }
#endif
```

Comment: I avoid `using` unless it *really* saves time without obscuring any clarity of the code. `Moq` is not much to type, and if it is only used once I would drop the `using`.

Comment: `using` **directives** are a compile time artifact anyway. (They're not `using` *statements*, those are used to automatically `Dispose` disposable objects)

Comment: Indeed, if the code that *uses* `Moq` is conditionally not-compiled, the `using` directive will be optimised away by the compiler.

Comment: I'd like to ask that we not focus on the example I gave and focus on the question at large please.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that is a good point. I'll revise my title.

Comment: Frank, there is no question wider question. If you *incorrectly* wrap a `using` directive in an `#if`, it might not build; if you "correctly" wrap one, you don't gain anything because you're doing something the compiler would essentially do itself. Your example covers this as well as any.

Comment: I see. If one of you want to write that up as the answer, I'll mark it as such.